# Trying to get property of non-object and undefined index erroe

Tags: php, mysqli

I just migrated a site based on custom CMS to new server. After migrating I am getting notices and warnings all over the admin area where content can be edited.

```
Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in database.php on line 69
Notice: Undefined index: in database.php on line 69
```

Following are the functions which are being used in the process:

```
function dbQuerySafener($query,$params=false) {
    $link= db_connect();
    if ($params) {
       foreach ($params as &$v) {
          $v = mysqli_real_escape_string($link,$v);
       }

       $sql_query = vsprintf( str_replace("?","'%s'",$query), $params );
    } else {
    $sql_query = $query;
 }
 return $sql_query;
}

// query returning ARRAY (many rows)
 function dbArray($query,$params=false) {
   $link= db_connect();
   $table_result=array();
   $r=0;
   $sql = dbQuerySafener($query, $params);
   $result = mysqli_query($link,$sql) or die(mysqli_error($link)." 
   <br>".$sql);
   while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
       $arr_row=array();
       $c=0;
       while ($c < mysqli_num_fields($result)) {
          $col = mysqli_fetch_field($result);
          $arr_row[$col -> name] = $row[$col -> name]; // line 69
          $c++;
       }
    $table_result[$r] = $arr_row;
    $r++;
    }
    return $table_result;
  }
```

It is working as follows:
A sql query will be passed to dbArray function, for example:

```
 $sql = "SELECT `id`, `emailAddress`, `name` FROM `gcms_users` 
 WHERE `active`=?";
 $data = dbArray($sql, array(1));
```

EXPECTED RESULT:
The above two functions will fetch the results from database which should contains field name and its value, example:

```
  Array ( [0] => Array ( [id] => 1 [emailAddress] => admin@email.com 
  [name] => John ) [1] => Array ( [id] => 1 [emailAddress] => 
  paul@email.com [name] => Paul ) )
```

ACTUAL RESULT:

```
  Array ( [0] => Array ( [id] => 1 [emailAddress] => admin@email.com [name] => John ) [1] => Array ( [] => ) )
```

There is some problem with dbArray() function while fetching the rows but I am not getting that what is missing here. Your help will be highly appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Check for MySQL errors.

Comment: @Utkanos It is returning a result but one row, it means there is some problem with code of fetching rows.

Comment: @NigelRen this is not my code. I am also trying to understand it but this is custom CMS developed by someone else.

Comment: "Trying to get property of non-object" does not suggest it's returning a result. It suggests an error.

Comment: I really feel sorry for you!  The code which is producing an error is copying field by field a result and then copying that to another array, something which `mysqli_fetch_all()` would do in one line.

Comment: @Utkanos can you please tell me from where I can check mysql error log ?

Comment: @NigelRen mysqli_fetch_all is fetching just the values not the fields name, I need fields names as well.

Comment: `mysqli_fetch_all()` with `MYSQLI_ASSOC` returns an associative array.  So the field names are the keys for the fields.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pointer of mysqli_fetch_field is not reset in your first while, try

`mysqli_field_seek($result, 0);` after `$r++;`

Comment: This is the correct answer, thanks you saved my day.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot re-loop mysqli_num_fields(). You can fetch the columns first then loop through data.

```
function dbArray($query,$params=false) {
       $link= db_connect();
       $table_result=array();
       $r=0;
       $sql = dbQuerySafener($query, $params);
       $result = mysqli_query($link,$sql) or die(mysqli_error($link)." 
       <br>".$sql);

       $columns = array();
       while($col = mysqli_num_fields($result)) {
        $columns[] = $col->name;
       }

       while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
           $arr_row = array();
           foreach($columns as $col){
              $arr_row[$col] = $row[$col];
           }
           $table_result[$r] = $arr_row;
           $r++;
        }
        return $table_result;
      }
```